# graph.microsoft drive/root/search returns only 1000 total

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My goal is to return all photos on a persons OneDrive.  Using the following query I get 5 pages with 200 entries each.  But my OnDrive has way more `jpg` entries.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='jpg')?select=*
```

I did see another post about limiting the results, which perhaps is being done in this case, but then how can I get a list of all the files that are photos?

Comment: Just to clarify, in the response for the request for the 5th page you do not get another `@odata.nextLink` value?

Comment: Right, it is missing.  I'm doing link = (string)fileList["@odata.nextLink"];, where fileList is a JObject, and it returns null.  BTW, today it's only returning 200 items, and it's null after the first call.  Swear I didn't change a thing with that part of the code.

Comment: Have you verified, that if you search for `jpg` online in your OneDrive account, you get more results including pagination?
My guess would be that there is some throttling/limitation on "broad queries", but I'm not aware of such a thing.

Comment: A search on my OneDrive for "jpg" shows me more than 1000, though I have to page down because of how it dynamically adds images.  But in one example I could select 1800 pictures.